# Subset pandas dataframe and assign different columns in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe :

```
>>> df
  product company code
0      P1      C1    X
1      P2      C2    X
2      P3      C3    Y
3      P4      C4    Z
4      P5      C5    C
```

I want to select `product` and `company` where the value in the code column is equal to `X`. Finally , have difference column names. So the output would look like :

```
>>> df
  product_name parent_company
0      P1      C1    
1      P2      C2
```

Because only `P1` and `P2` has `X` under the `Code` column.

I have the solution using a for loop. Whats the most stylish way to achieve this in a line ?

Comment: `df.loc[df['code'].eq('X'), ['product', 'company']]`

Comment: how to rename the column in the same line ?

Comment: `df.rename(columns={"product": "product_name", "company": "parent_company"})`

Comment: @RameshK You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in comments:

Show the columns `product` and `company` where value in code column is `x`

`df.loc[df['code'].eq('X'), ['product', 'company']]`

Rename columns:

`df.rename(columns={"product": "product_name", "company": "parent_company"})`

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to chain all in one call:

```
new_df = (df.query("code == 'X'")
            .reindex(columns=['product', 'company'])
            .set_axis(['product_name', 'parent_company'], axis='columns', inplace=False)
         )
```